# why is my linux system experiencing "Log I/O error Detected. Shutting down filesystem" problem

Tags: filesystems, xfs

system info:

```
[root@cpe ~]# uname -a
Linux cpe 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@cpe ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

[root@cpe ~]# df
Filesystem              1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl_cpe-root  34721216 34721196        20 100% /
devtmpfs                 32843124        0  32843124   0% /dev
tmpfs                    32855080        0  32855080   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    32855080   942644  31912436   3% /run
tmpfs                    32855080        0  32855080   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl_cpe-home  16947200    32944  16914256   1% /home
/dev/sda1                 1038336    85484    952852   9% /boot
tmpfs                     6571016        0   6571016   0% /run/user/0
[root@cpe ~]# mount | grep root
/dev/mapper/cl_cpe-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

problem:
when system is running, there are error log as below. then can't run any command line.

```
XFS (dm-0): metadata I/O error: block 0x2128c70 ("xlog_iodone") error 5 numblks 64
XFS (dm-0): Log I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
XFS (dm-0): Please umount the filesystem and rectify the problems(s)
XFS (dm-0): metadata I/O error: block 0x2128c7f ("xlog_iodone") error 5 numblks 64
XFS (dm-0): metadata I/O error: block 0x2128c82 ("xlog_iodone") error 5 numblks 64
```

Who can help me to analyze or locate the problem.
Thanks in advance.